# Error in sending a data to an endpoint, what I expect does not arrive, I am missing a condition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

basically what I'm doing is running through an array of questions, which I have to answer with a RadioButton, so I have this

```
<IonList>
                {answerQuestion && answerQuestion.map((question:any) => {
                  return (
                    <IonRadioGroup
                    onIonChange={e => this.setSelected(e.detail.value, question.name)}>
                    <div className='radio-1' key={question.id}>
                      <IonLabel >{question.name}</IonLabel>
                    <div className="optionsQuestion">
                    <div className="optionQuestionYes">
                      <IonLabel className='radio-2'>Si</IonLabel>
                      <IonRadio value="Si"></IonRadio>
                    </div>
                    <div className="optionQuestionNo">
                      <IonLabel className='radio-2'>No</IonLabel>
                      <IonRadio value="No"></IonRadio>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </IonRadioGroup>
                  )})}
                
              </IonList>
```

So there my questions are painted and the options to answer in this case the value is Yes / No, what is happening to me? that when I answer and cancel and send the answer to the put, in the database it answers the two questions, but gives the answer the last value, for example if in question one I put Yes, and in the 2nd I put No, when I send it to save it, put the two questions No.

```
  setSelected = (answer:string, name:string) =>{ 
this.setState({
  question:
  { [name]: answer,
    [name]: answer}
})
}
```

What I want is an object to be saved like this:

```
{
"questions": {
    "question 1?": "yes",
    "question 2?": "no"
}    
}
```

That I can change those values ​​independently, what I'm going through now is that it modifies both of me, with the last value selected in the radiobuttom.

I have a console.log recording what it does when I click the options and it prints this to me: It asks one with the value I select and then the 2

[image]

The most I have achieved is to send the object, but with only one question answered, but I need to send both.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your radio buttons are calling

`setSelected`

which in turn sets the state:

`this.setState({   question:   { [name]: answer, [name]: answer} })`

this saves your current answer and when the other button is clicked it gets overridden. you should save an array of quest/answer objects to the state.
To achieve this you should have class level variable for array of objects and example can be found [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove)

IN the constructor of the component, initialize the questions

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
    this.state = {
      "questions": {
           "question 1?": "yes",
           "question 2?": "no"
              }  
       };
  }
```

and in your setSelected method something like this should work

```
setSelected = (answer:string, name:string) =>{ 
  this.setState(state => {
    state["questions"][name] = answer;     
    return state;
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, when it clicks, it calls the setSelected function, I understand what is happening, but could you give me an example? I don't have much experience, I would really appreciate it